# Смена стиля при изменении расположения курсора мыши

Tags: javascript, mouse-event

Задание: Навязчивая реклама. При выходе со страницы сайта должно появляться сообщение.

Когда, для проверки работоспособности функции, использовал функцию 
alert(), в браузере сообщение исправно появлялось. А вот изменить 
стиль, чтобы в браузере появлялся блок с сообщением, не получается.
Chrome пишет, что ошибка функции.

```
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 2rem;            
        }
        #box{            
            margin: 30px 20% 0 20%;
            background-color: green;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: left;
            color: beige;
            font-size: 2rem;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>
            В этом задании нельзя просто взять и уйти с сайта.
        </h1>
        <div id="box">
            Навязчивая реклама!!!
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let box = document.getElementById('box');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{            
            if(e.clientY < 50) 
                box.style.display = '';
            else 
                box.style.display = 'none';

        })
    </script>
</body>
```

//Пробовал такой вариант, всё равно не работает:

```
        if(e.clientY < 50) 
             box.style.visibility = 'visible';
         else 
             box.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: 1) Попробуйте для начала проверить, срабатывает ли событие в целом. Замените код условия на `if(e.clientY < 50) 
             alert('visible');
         else 
             alert('hidden');`

Comment: *Chrome пишет, что ошибка функции.* - а что за ошибка то?

Comment: if(e.clientY < 50) alert('visible'); else alert('hidden'); Да, срабатывает. Chrome, говорит что ошибка функции.

Comment: Что такое *ошибка функции*? У хрома нет такой ошибки :-) Пожалуйста, приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: "102 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function"

Comment: Вот сразу бы так. У вас опечатка document.getElement**s**ById.

Comment: Это хром так пишет, в коде у меня: let box = document.getElementById('box'); Чтобы меньше делать ошибок, использую emmet в VScode.

Answer (score 0):

При уходе пользователя со страницы лучше попробовать использовать другие обработчики событий, например

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  if ( !confirm("Do you realy want out?")) return false;
}
```

Comment: Я внес Ваш скрипт в свою базу. Но мне нужно сделать задание.